# Python dict into MySQL executemany

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary, tuples

My statement should match syntax, but I get error 
`"Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement`

```
stmt = "UPDATE abbcards SET carPlate = '%(values)s' WHERE carId =%(id)s"
params = [tuple(cusSurname.values()), tuple(cusSurname.keys())]
cur.executemany(stmt, params)
```

What's wrong? I've defined the `operation` and `seq_params` variables.

Comment: Your `stmt` strings makes it appear you would be passing a dict, but you're passing a list of tuples? Shouldn't your params be a dict with keys 'values' and 'id'?

Comment: Nope. Only lists and tuples. e.g. `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Parameters for query must be list or tuple.`
Checked it more then twice. Safiest way is to use tuples.

Comment: @ThePjot, of course you were right.

Answer (score 2):

@ThePjot is somewhat right in their comment. You are using named placeholders in your query string (`%(values)s` and `%(id)s`), so you have to pass the parameters in the form of a dict.

**BUT**, you also call `executemany` which needs a list or tuple of *parameters*. Many times, `executemany` does nothing else than calling `execute` multiple times while iterating over `params`, passing an element of parameters in every iteration.
That means, each element of `params` must contain a full set of parameters for the query.

Looking at your query string you need two parameters to be substituted.

```
stmt = "UPDATE abbcards SET carPlate = '%(values)s' WHERE carId =%(id)s"
# Side note: the quote chars around %(values)s are quite certainly wrong here
```

From your code examples, one could assume that `cusSurname` is a dict.
Let's say it looks like this:

```
cusSurname = {'1': 'a1b1c1',
              '2': 'a2b2c2',
              '3': 'a3b3c3'}
```

What you are doing in the code above, is passing all the keys and all the values of cusSurname to `executemany`.

```
params = [('a1b1c1', 'a2b2c2', 'a3b3c3'), ('1', '2', '3')]
```

This would lead to a final query string of:

```
UPDATE abbcards SET carPlate = '\'a1b1c1\'' WHERE carId ='a2b2c2'
```

... with one element from the first parameter tuple not being substituted, which leads to `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement`, before the second statement could be formed from the string and the params, which would look like:

```
UPDATE abbcards SET carPlate = '\'1\'' WHERE carId ='2'
```

... and raise the same exception.
What you'll want to do, is end up with a list/tuple of dicts consisting of individual items of your `cusSurname`:

```
stmt = "UPDATE abbcards SET carPlate = %(values)s WHERE carId =%(id)s"
params = [dict({'id': k, 'values': v}) for k,v in cusSurname.items()]
# [{'id': '1', 'values': 'a1b1c1'}, {'id': '2', 'values': 'a2b2c2'}, {'id': '3', 'values': 'a3b3c3'}]
cur.executemany(stmt, params)
```

Or switch to positional params:

```
stmt = "UPDATE abbcards SET carPlate = %s WHERE carId =%s"
params = [tuple(i) for i in cusSurname.items()]
# [('1', 'a1b1c1'), ('2', 'a2b2c2'), ('3', 'a3b3c3')]
cur.executemany(stmt, params)
```